# unmet dependencies in cairo installation (Ubuntu 14.04 LTS - 64 Bit)

Tags: node.js, linux, canvas, ubuntu-14.04, qr-code

I'm trying to install Cairo on Ubuntu 14.04 64 Bit but it shows unmet dependencies. I'm using following command to install cairo

> **sudo apt-get install libcairo2-dev**

Above command returning following error:

> The following packages have unmet dependencies:
>   libcairo2-dev : 
>     Depends: **libxext-dev** but it is not going to be installed.
>       Depends: **libglib2.0-dev** but it is not going to be installed.
>   E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.

As per error, I tried to install "libxext-dev" package using *"sudo apt-get install libxext-dev"* command and now again got error for unmet dependency of following package:

> **libxext6** 
>   ERROR: Depends: libxext6 (= 2:1.3.2-1) but 2:1.3.2-1ubuntu0.0.14.04.1 is to be installed

So now I tried to install "libxext6" but it's already installed. Not sure then why "sudo apt-get install libxext-dev" says unmet dependencies error.

Please help me to resolve out this issue if anybody know how to resolve out this issue.

Thanks

Comment: » sudo apt-get install libcairo2-dev « : The right command is `sudo apt-get update &&  sudo apt-get install libcairo2-dev`

Comment: Thanks Knud, Yes I already tried with `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install libcairo2-dev' and also tried again now but still same result. No luck.

Comment: First : No issues here. (A Danish server.) ... So please try again : `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install libcairo2-dev` ... and if no luck, then please change mirror,  in `/etc/apt/sources.list` ... to another link address, e.g. http://se.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu ... i.e. a remote server is often more reliable, and can be faster than a local link.

Comment: Thanks Knud, I changed mirror server and it installed without any error. Thanks for your help.